# Cannot fetch login credentials from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot fetch admin credentials. I have checked the script numerous times, but cannot detect the problem. Your expert eyes can find something.

loginshed.php

```
<?php     
    include('../settings/config.php');

    $username= $_POST["username"];
    $password= $_POST["password"];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `adminlogin` WHERE `username`='".$username."' and `password`= '".base64_encode($password)."' ; ";
    $res=dbQuery($sql) or die(mysql_error().$sql);
    $rec=dbNumRows($res);
    if($rec > 0)
    {
        $s = dbQuery("update `adminlogin` set `logintime`= '".$totaldate."' where `username`='".$username."' ; ");
        $_SESSION["adminusername"]=$username;
        header("location: adminhome.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: index.php?msg=error");
    }       
?>
```

form

```
    <form name="login" action="loginshed.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate2()">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:200px;" class="input" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:200px;" class="input"/>
    <button type="submit" name="btnsubmit" class="input" >Login</button>&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="input" >Reset</button>
```

Comment: any errors? does the database contain your columns and data? what exactly happens???

Comment: It redirects me to index.php?msg=error.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You may not be connecting to the database. Why are you using `base64_encode()` for the passwords?

Comment: add the following after each database action including the sql: `or die(mysql_error());`  this will help in finding the problem, also you don't sem to have set the connection for the database.. you need to do `$res = $dbQuery($con,$sql); `, i think that is how it works for command line php.. check the manual. also try and provide all the important code

Answer (score -1):

you might find :http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php
 a little more convienant to use, select row based on username and then verify the password vs the hash.
boolean password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )